# Set current language in magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2.2, locale

I want to set the current language to the language what i want.
I did URL redirect but at i am not able to set cookies for store.

Comment: You want to set language for admin panel or front side?

Comment: I wan to set the current language from frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a controller in your Custom Extension as given below to change Store Language.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Company\OrderDevice\Helper\Data;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManagerInterface;

protected $_resultJsonFactory;

protected $_httpContext;
protected $_storeRepository;
protected $storeCookieManager;




public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreCookieManagerInterface $storeCookieManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory        
    ) {

        $this->_storeManagerInterface        = $storeManager;
        $this->storeCookieManager = $storeCookieManager;
        $this->_httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->_storeRepository = $storeRepository;
        $this->_resultJsonFactory   = $resultJsonFactory;        
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


 public function execute(){
   $fromStore= 'default'; // English
   $toStore  = 'cn';      // Chinese
   $store = $this->_storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode($toStore);
   $this->_httpContext->setValue(Store::ENTITY, $toStore, $fromStore);
   $this->storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);   
   $result = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();       
   $message  = __('Contact Us');    
   return $result->setData(array(
                    'success' => 1,
                    'error' => 0,
                    'message' => $message
                   ));   

 }

}
```